# Getting character values in Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a table `Assessment` which has (among others) two columns, `CurrentGrade` and `PreviousGrade`, both of which are defined as `char(1)`.  A grade is a symbol from A to Z.

Now I want to write a query to get the difference between the current grade and the previous grade of all records in `Assessment`, to be expressed as a number, e.g. if previous is A and current is D, then the difference is 3.

I would have done something like this:

```
var q = db.Assessments.Select(a => new { a.ID, Diff = a.CurrentGrade[0] - a.PreviousGrade[0] });
```

... except that this doesn't work, because there's no SQL translation for `String.getChars`.

And I don't want to do this in local memory, because in my real code, this is just part of a big "where" clause that involves other expressions that must be done in Linq to Entities.

Any recommendations how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **Linq-To-Entities**, you can use `SqlFunctions.Ascii`:

```
using System.Data.Objects.SqlClient;

var result = db.Assessments.Select(a => new { a.id, 
    Diff = SqlFunctions.Ascii(a.CurrentGrade).Value - SqlFunctions.Ascii(a.PreviousGrade).Value });
```

Note that if `CurrentGrade` is higher (A) than `PreviousGrade` (D), you'll get an answer of `-3` which is reverse of what you ***may*** want... So you may want to multiply by `-1` to get the true direction of the grade difference.

```
var result = db.Assessments.Select(a => new { a.id, 
    Diff = (SqlFunctions.Ascii(a.CurrentGrade).Value - SqlFunctions.Ascii(a.PreviousGrade).Value) * -1 });
```

Comment: I thought he was using Linq-To-Sql for some reason, not sure why. Added the Linq-To-Entities version.

Comment: Hmmm. SqlFunctions.Difference returns a value between 0 and 4, it's about SOUNDEX values of a string, not the integer value of a string / char... see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188753.aspx (which is the sql server translation of the function)

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus: Ha you're right. I was testing with A - D and my result was 3. Should have been -3 but I overlooked it. The Ascii function should definitely work! I need some coffee this morning!!!

Comment: Thanks :) It was a good exercise. I always learn something new answering people's questions.